# How to output logs in custom pattern using logbook-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, logback

I have a spring application, which is using logbook logger for request/response logging

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
   <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.zalando.logbook: TRACE
```

logback is  logging the incoming and outgoing response as below

```
2022-11-09T09:00:51,084Z {"origin":"remote","type":"request","correlation":"c6d7a74....}
```

how can I make it log  this way?

```
2022-11-09T09:00:51.036210Z - info: {"origin":"remote","type":"request","correlation":"c6d7a74...}
```

Tried using the pattern in logback.xml nothing seems to work

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.zalando.logbook.json.JsonHttpLogFormatte">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show us your conf in logback.xml ?

Comment: resources/logback.xml looks like this               
<configuration>
    <appender name="console" class="org.zalando.logbook.json.JsonHttpLogFormatter">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by modifying `resources/log4j2.properties` by adding this line `appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} - info: %msg%n`

File looks like this

```
name = requestlogger

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} - info: %msg%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = info
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```